# Issue with RegExp and IE

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace some text (class name) using this function. It works on Chrome but not on IE, any ideas why? this is the actual website [website link](http://www.michal-mudrik.com/index.php/en/projects/housing/house%20binyamina).

The horizontal menu where it says "housing" should turn grey:

```
<li class="mainlevel_active-fade" id="menuitem_1-fade">
```

should become

```
<li class="mainlevel-fade" id="menuitem_1-fade">
```

JavaScript:

```
var divText = "";
var toReplace = '<li class="mainlevel_active-fade" id="menuitem_1-fade">';
var replacement = '<li class="mainlevel-fade" id="menuitem_1-fade">';

function findMyText(toReplace, replacement) {

     if (divText.length == 0) {
          divText = document.getElementById("header-left-b").innerHTML;
     }
     var re = new RegExp(toReplace, "ig");     
     var replaced = "";
     if (replacement.length > 0) {
          replaced = divText.replace(re, replacement);
     }
     else {
          var Text = "<div>" + toReplace + "</div>";
          replaced = divText.replace(re, Text);
     }
     document.getElementById("header-left-b").innerHTML = replaced;
}

findMyText(toReplace, replacement);
```

i ended up finding a simple way of displaying different classes in different modules, so dropped this attempt.thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a regexp here? You are doing classic plain string substitution. Plus, you really shouldn't be using `innerHTML` here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use a regexp here? You are doing classic plain string substitution. Plus, you really shouldn't be using `innerHTML` at all here.

`innerHTML` probably is the reason why it does not work. I assume that IE will produce a different HTML representation of your header than Chrome does, and your string is then not found. E.g. **any** browser might serialize the tag *correctly* (the order of attributes is undefined!) as:

```
<li id="menuitem_1-fade" class="mainlevel_active-fade">
```

and boom, your approach no longer works.

Use DOM instead of string manipulation. It's faster and more reliable.

Comment: i ended up finding a simple way of displaying different classes in different modules, so dropped this attempt.thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

How about this ..

```
my_li = document.getElementById('menuitem_1-fade');

my_li.className -= 'mainlevel_active-fade';
my_li.className += 'mainlevel-fade';
```